# The proposition about invariant subspace and representation matrix (triangular)

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

$f : V \rightarrow V$ : linear mapping

$ \text{dim}V = n$

Proposition;

If Invariant subspace $W_1, W_2, \cdots ,W_n(=V) \quad (\text{dim}W_k=k)$

$\quad s.t. \quad W_1 \subset W_2 \subset \cdots \subset W_n(=V)$ exist,

then $f$ has a triangular representation matrix.

Is this proof correct?

Proof

Because $\text{dim}W_1 = 1$, I let $\{ v_1 \}$ bese of $W_1$.

Because $\text{dim}W_2 = 2$ and $W_1 \subset W_2$, I can let $\{ v_1, v_2 \}$ base of $W_2$.

I repeat the same thing from $W_3$ to $W_n$,

I can let  $\{ v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_n \}$ base of $W_n(=V)$.

Then, considering $f(W_k )\subset W_k$,

I can express

$ 
f(v_1)=c_{11} v_1 \\
f(v_2)=c_{12} v_1 + c_{22} v_2 \\
\quad \vdots \\
f(v_n) = c_{1n} v_1 + c_{2n} v_2 + \cdots + c_{nn} v_n$.

Then, representation matrix is

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & \cdots & c_{1n} \\
0   & c_{22} & c_{23} & \cdots & c_{2n} \\
0   & 0   & c_{33} & \cdots & c_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & c_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: What step are you unsure of?

Comment: @PQH I let  {v_1, v_2}  base of W_2. That is, I created base of W_2 using base of W_1. Can I really do it? I'm unsure of this.

Comment: Yes, you can always add vectors to a linear independent set in order to get a basis. Take $\{v_1\}\subset W_2$ and $v_2\in W_2\setminus \langle\{v_1\}\rangle$. The set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis of $W_2$. Now take $v_3\in W_3\setminus W_2$, etc.